# Java - Data types used as keys in maps

Tags: java, maps, key

What types of data types are admissible to use as keys in maps in java? Is it ok to use a double? How about a String?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the API as there may be limitations on permissible types for keys depending on the specific map. Also, you can only use reference types but not primitive types. So double won't work, but Double is fine. Finally, the key should preferably not be mutable as this can cause aberrant behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any object type.
But in order to get correct behavior the type has to have a hashCode() and equals() functions correctly implemented.

So if you want to use `double` you should instead use `Double` and because of boxing and unboxing you can actually pass `double` values to the functions like `add()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`doubles` won't work, as they are primitive type, that is, you cannot define a map `Map<double,String>`. However, you can define `Map<Double,String>` and then use a double value for the `put` method (thanks to autoboxing).

The caveat for abitary object in a map is, that unless the `equal` and `hashcode` methods are overridden, equality is based on references, which might not be the desired behavior. (So you might end up with two entries, where you would only expect one.)

Answer (score 0):

For a key you can use any `Object` that is unique to your dataset. You cannot use `int` or `double` but you can use `Integer` or `Double`. Please note that a key can only have one value, hence the requirement for a object that is unique. If you add the same key twice only the second value will be stored in the `Map`

Answer (score 0):

you must use an object
if you want to use double you can use the Double wrapper  class 
you can't use primitive data type like int or long or double if you want to use one you can look for the wrapper class that represent it

String is okey since it's a Class

Answer (score 0):

Primitive data types are not allowed, better you Wrapper class to store your data in map.
Moreover, until and unless you override your equal and hashcode method, using map is of not much use.